# Inherit background color and other attributes for many UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, ios9, uistoryboard

For an iOS9+/Swift 3 app with many UIViewControllers, what is the best practice way of inheriting the same background colors and other common attributes (fonts, spacing, etc...).  Is it best to have a common base class?  Or some sort of protocol?

Comment: "If your question could be answered by an entire book, or has **many valid answers**, it's probably too broad for our format"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because most visual attributes are associated with specific UIViews and UIView subclasses (like UILabel, UIButton, etc.), I would suggest that having this handled at the UIViewController level is forcing the view controller to be responsible for too many details specific to other classes.

Apple's built-in mechanism for setting global visual attributes on various views is the UIAppearance API. There's a [good overview of that on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/)

The downside of using UIAppearance is that is doesn't easily accommodate variations in styling, like some buttons being red and some buttons being blue. It's basically a fixed default appearance for all instances of a certain view across the app.

I personally prefer using a dedicated styling framework that allows for applying combinations predefined styles to views.  I [have written about this](http://www.danielhall.io/a-grand-unification-theory-of-ios-styling) and also created a [framework](http://stylish.danielhall.io) to facilitate creating styles for UIKit components and applying and previewing them inside storyboards.

Comment: Another approach to define composable & reusable styles, if you're interested: [StyleSheet](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a constants file with UI constants.  Just refer to those variables in all view controllers and if you need to make changes everything else will change too.

You could also have an extension for certain things. I usually have an extension on UIColor that returns a color and I can change it in the extension and it will change everywhere else.

e.g.

```
extension UIColor{
    class func selectedBlue() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.58, blue:0.97, alpha:1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a common base class for a desired component e.g for setting background color of your views, Create a subclass let its name be BackgroundView.

```
class UHBView: UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()  
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor(); //Any color you want
    }

}
```

Now set this subclass as a custom class in identity inspector in Interface Builder for any view.

[image]

Comment: That seems like a runtime attribute and I'm under the impression that protocols are better than inheritance in Swift ...but I really don't know.